# Workaround for dynamically generating a structure - Matlab/Octave issues

Tags: matlab, indexing, data-structures, octave, cell-array

I have many, many sets of data in .csv format that I've organized by a file name standard so I can use regular expressions for the second time ever.  I have, however, run into a slight problem.  My data files are titled things like, "2012001_C335_2000MHZ_P_1111.CSV".  There are four years of interest, two frequencies, and four different C335-style labels to describe locations.  I have a significant amount of data processing to do on each of these files, so I'd like to read them all into one giant structure and then do my processing on different parts of it.  I'm writing:

```
for ix_id = 1:length(ids)
 for ix_years = 1:2:length(ids_years{ix_id})
  for ix_frq = 1:length(frqs)
   st = [ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq}'_P_1111.CSV'];
   data.(ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq}).(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}]) =...
        dlmread(st);
  end
 end
end
```

All `ids` variables are 1x4 cell arrays where each cell contains strings.

This produces the errors:
"Error: a cs-list cannot be further indexed"
and
"Error: invalid assignment to cs-list outside multiple assignment"

I did an internet search for these errors and found a few posts with dates ranging from 2010 to 2012, such as [this one](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Initializing-structs-with-mixed-non-empty-fields-and-leads-to-empty-structs-td4504166.html) and [this one](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/a-cs-list-cannot-be-further-indexed-td1638235.html), where the author suggests it's a problem with Octave itself.  I can do a workaround that involves defining two separate structures by removing the innermost for loop over ix_frq and replacing the lines beginning with "st" and "data" with

```
data.1500.(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}]) = ...
  dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids{ix_id} '_1500MHZ_P_1111.CSV']);
data.2000.(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}]) = ...
  dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids{ix_id} '_2000MHZ_P_1111.CSV']);
```

so it seems that the trouble arises when I try to make a more nested structure.  I'm wondering if this is unique to Octave or the same in Matlab, and also if there's a slicker workaround than defining two separate structures since I'd like this to be as portable as possible.  If you have any insight as to the meaning of the error message, I'm interested in that too.  Thanks!

EDIT:  Here is the full script - now generates a few dummy .csv files.  Runs on Octave v. 3.8

```
clear all
%this program tests the creation of various structures.  The end goal is to have a structure of the format frequency.beamname.year(1) = matrix of the appropriate file
A = rand(3,2);
csvwrite('2009103_C115_1500MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2009103_C115_2000MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2010087_C115_1500MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2010087_C115_2000MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2009103_C335_1500MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2009103_C335_2000MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2010087_C335_1500MHZ.CSV',A)
csvwrite('2010087_C335_2000MHZ.CSV',A)

data = dir('*.CSV');  %imports all of the files of a directory
files = {data.name};  %cell array of filenames
nfiles = numel(files);

%find all the years
years = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},regexp(files,'\d{7}','match'),'UniformOutput',false));  
%find all the beam names
ids = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},regexp(files,'([C-I]\d{3})|([C-I]\d{1}[C-I]\d{2})','match'),'UniformOutput',false));
%find all the frequencies
frqs = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},regexp(files,'\d{4}MHZ','match'),'UniformOutput',false));

%now, vectorize to cover all the beams
for id_ix = 1:length(ids)
  expression_yrs = ['(\d{7})(?=_' ids{id_ix} ')'];
  listl_yrs = regexp(files,expression_yrs,'match');
  ids_years{id_ix} = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},listl_yrs(cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x),listl_yrs)),'UniformOutput',false));  %returns the years for data collected with both the 1500 and 2000 MHZ antennas along each of thebeams
  expression_frqs = ['(?<=' ids{id_ix} '_)(\d{4}MHZ)']; 
  listfrq = regexp(files,expression_frqs,'match'); %finds every frequency that was collected for C115, C335
  ids_frqs{id_ix} = unique(cellfun(@(x)x{1},listfrq(cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x),listfrq)),'UniformOutput',false));
end

%% finally, dynamically generate a structure data.Beam.Year.Frequency
%this works
for ix_id = 1:length(ids)
  for ix_year = 1:length(ids_years{ix_id})
    data1500.(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}])=dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids_frqs{1}{1} '.CSV']);
    data2000.(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}])=dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids_frqs{1}{2} '.CSV']);
  end
end

%this doesn't work
for ix_id=1:length(ids)
  for ix_year=1:length(ids_years{ix_id})
    for ix_frq = 1:numel(frqs)
        data.(['F' ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq}]).(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}])=dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq} '.CSV']);
    end 
  end
end
```

Hopefully, that helps clarify the question - I am not sure of the etiquette here with posting edits and code.

Comment: The error you are getting is that somehow on your indexing, you must be indexing a [cs-list (comma-separated list)](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Comma-Separated-Lists.html) which cannot be index. Can you give example input to your code so we can replicate the problem and help more? It's a bit convoluted at the moment.

Comment: Hi @carandraug  - thanks for taking a look at this.  I've posted the full code above, although I am not sure if that will answer your question.  I think the problem, if it is the cs-list issue, must be in the frequency loop `for ix_frq`, but I'm just not able to see it.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood me. Can you give an example where you define a a small test `ids` and `ids_years`, right before entering the loop, so that we can and replicate the error in our own computers?

Comment: Ah, my mistake - `ids = {'C115'; 'C335'; 'D115'; 'G5F55'}` , `ids_years = {'2010087';'2012001';'2013002';'2014003'}` , and `ids_frqs = {'1500MHZ'; '2000MHZ'}`

Comment: look at the variables used inside the loop and give the variables necessary to replicate your error. That's still not enough. Can you put a piece of code, that when entered in a new octave session, will show your problem?

Comment: Third time's the charm, hopefully...  The edited block of code at the end there will generate a few dummy files since the problem is in the dlmread part.  Sorry for the confusion, and harass me as needed if I'm still missing the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you get to the for loop that is causing a problem, data already exists and is a struct array.

```
octave> data
data =

  8x1 struct array containing the fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum
    statinfo
```

When you select a field from a struct array you will get a cs-list (comma-separate list) unless you also index which of the structs in the struct array.  See:

```
octave> data.name
ans = 2009103_C115_1500MHZ.CSV
ans = 2009103_C115_2000MHZ.CSV
ans = 2009103_C335_1500MHZ.CSV
ans = 2009103_C335_2000MHZ.CSV
ans = 2010087_C115_1500MHZ.CSV
ans = 2010087_C115_2000MHZ.CSV
ans = 2010087_C335_1500MHZ.CSV
ans = 2010087_C335_2000MHZ.CSV
octave> data(1).name
ans = 2009103_C115_1500MHZ.CSV
```

So when you do:

```
data.(...) = dlmread (...);
```

you don't get what you were expecting on the left hand side, you will get a cs-list. But I'm guessing this is accidental, since `data` at the moment only has filenames, so simply create a new empty struct:

```
data = struct (); # this will clear your previous data
for ix_id=1:length(ids)
  for ix_year=1:length(ids_years{ix_id})
    for ix_frq = 1:numel(frqs)
        data.(['F' ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq}]).(ids{ix_id}).(['Y' ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year}])=dlmread([ids_years{ix_id}{ix_year} '_' ids{ix_id} '_' ids_frqs{ix_id}{ix_frq} '.CSV']);
    end 
  end
end
```

I would also recommend to think better about your current solution. This code looks overcomplicated to me.

Comment: This looks great and makes sense.  I'm surprised I overlooked that - seems very obvious now, but as you say, the code is overcomplicated.  It is a result of having a constantly evolving set of data that might include different frequencies and different locations, so it seemed easier to build structures from filenames.  I really appreciate your help!